# Windows time keeps changing automatically

Tags: windows-7, time

Every 30 mins or sometimes much longer the system time changes with the event ---
 The time service has set the time with offset 15481355650727981 seconds.

The time always reverts back 37 hours to the current time, visually it goes back 1 hour, PM switches to AM and Monday becomes Sunday.

Adding a task to sync the time every 5 minutes helps but doesn't solve the problem...

I have read this answer, but I do not think I have the same root cause.  [Windows 7 time keeps changing by itself](https://superuser.com/questions/706848/windows-7-time-keeps-changing-by-itself)

I have attached a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f73lm.jpg) of the event

[image: screen shot]

Comment: 15481355650727981 seconds is a whole lot more than 37 hours!

Comment: disable NTP time sync in control panel->date&time settings

Comment: Run from the command line: w32tm /query /status
It will give you some diagnostic information such as the clock source.